# HDMI man in the middle

Tags: hdmi

I want to build a screen grabber that sits between HDMI devices - like a television - to capture screenshot and send to a server every interval.

Before I buy hardware I do not need, can it be dome with Raspberry PI ?

Comment: does the Raspberry Pi have an HDMI input port?

Comment: https://auvidea.eu/b100-hdmi-to-csi-2-bridge/

Comment: looks like you may have answered your own question